# Deep Autoencoder in TensorFlow to learn pseudo-sentence embeddings

Tags: autoencoders, sparse, tensorflow

I am stuck with a problem since days which is to find a right set-up for an Autoencoder that learns dense representations of sparse textual representations, word order is not relevant which is why I did not use skip-gram or CBOW. I would like to use these embeddings as features for another neural network.

**Data structure:**

- Vocabulary Size (columns): 4495
- Unique Pseudo-Sentences (rows): 1452789

(Each sentence, basically a list of numerically encoded tags, is one-hot-encoded given the vocabulary and thus a vector of length 4495 which contains a 1 for very tag in the vocabulary, and 0 respectively)
The resulting matrix is pretty sparse, on average each pseudo-sentence has 11 tags.

**Target:**
Learn a dense embedding for each pseudo-sentence

**Measures:**
I am currently observing 4 measures across training

- Accuracy
- Prediction
- Recall
- RMSE

I adapted the TF Autoencoder Example from here:
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/autoencoder.py

I changed from sigmoid to rely activation, except of the output (final decoded) layer and tried different set-up around 2 and 3 hidden layers:

- [1024, 256, 64]
- [2048, 256, 32]
- [1024, 128]
- [1024, 64]
- [512, 32]
- ...
- learning rates: {0.03, 0.01, 0.003}
- batch_sizes: {512, 1024}

My biggest problem so far is that accuracy is stuck around .70 and .82, but even more crucial is my ridiculously low recall of ~0.007 which is decreasing during learning. Loss is decreasing and the precision is very good ~0.99.
Recall and Precision are calculated by taking a threshold, currently 0.8 against which I evaluate the predictions. That means every value below that threshold is taken as 0 (word not in sentence) and every equal or above that threshold is mapped to 1 (word appears in sentence). I know, this is quite arbitrary, but somehow I have to find out whether large accuracy just stems from predicting 0 for all due to the large sparsity.

I have to get recall up with the embeddings, but I don't like to test even more different architectures since I don't believe that this is the main problem.

Has anyone some helpful suggestions? Maybe changing to another loss function or trying a deeper architecture?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're only learning an embedding, what do you mean by recall? Also, could you expand on what are the "Unique Pseudo-Sentences" or how you obtained them? And I think the batch sizes are really big, did you try small values? (the last point is not critical, just wondering)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I just added a not rgd. how I derived recall (and precision) values. The recall is basically calculated as from the words appearing in the sentence how many were retrieved in the prediction. Ea. "pseudo-sentence" is a collection of unique tags for an item (recommender system context). I just called it pseudo-sentence due to its agglomeration of words, but without a meaningful order. Regarding the batch size, I will have a look.